# Type hinting for loading a machine learning PMML model pipeline using `pickle.load()`

Tags: python, pickle, type-hinting, pmml

i have a function like:

```
def load_model(model_path: str) -> ???:
    with open("XXX.pkl", "rb") as f:
        model_pipeline = pickle.load(f)

    return model_pipeline
```

My question is what type hint i should specify for the output? thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `pypmml.Model`? Strictly speaking, it's the type of the value originally written to `XXX.pkl` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner what if it's a model and we don;t know if it's a PMML model or not? can i just use `Model`?

Comment: If you don't already know the type, I don't think you can provide a *static* type hint more accurate than `object`.